# How I can see camera ip use with webview on Android 2.3?

Tags: android

My camera is a 7Links and this is my codec:

```
    String url="http://192.168.0.8/main.htm";
    webview.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword("192.168.0.8", "", "admin", "");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

when I run the code webview appears the black, Where is the failure?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that is uses a plugin/activex/windows or desktop specific plugin of some sort that doesn't work in android? What does it look like in a desktop browser, what do you get when you right click in the camera window on the desktop? What does the html look like?

Comment: How can I sent you the html? Only I have 580 characters. Thank you!